# "Class web does not exist" with Laravel Chatter

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently updated my app from Laravel 5.1 to 5.3.

Soon after this, I tried installing chatter.

I followed the instructions, found here: https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter

save for that instead of adding the yields to master.blade.php(I don't have one), I added them to templates/default.blade.php (essentially the same thing).

After following all the steps, I went to check out the page localhost/forums, and it returned this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: 

Class web does not exist
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Google shows that this has already been answered on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/reflectionexception-class-web-does-not-exit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have `$middlewareGroups` in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`.
Or add it from [app/Http/Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php) at line 28.
If already there be sure it have

```
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

in `web` .




You should also check and add

```
'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

in `$routeMiddleware` array.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0